# Is there any indication that X-24 is capable of intelligent thought?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the 2017 film "Logan", X-24 is apparently the latest culmination of the Weapon X program, but is basically just

> a slightly enhanced, younger version of Logan himself.

Throughout the film, X-24 doesn't speak and generally just kills people. His handlers use very basic commands to control him, but as we see on-screen he can choose whether or not to obey those commands. He uses very little (if any) strategy in his fights, and basically just acts like Wolverine does in berserker mode.

Given his origins, this all seems rather odd. As he is presented on-screen, he's more like a dog let off its chain temporarily, and would be pretty useless on solo missions.

**Is there any indication - on-screen or otherwise - that X-24 is capable of intelligent thought?**

Comment: Whether he can or not we don't ever get a chance to see as he's always 'activated' in his berserker mode.

Comment: I'd say he's *capable*, just not developed to do so. If you remember, Dr. Rice says something along the lines of "If you want the perfect weapon, you have to grow it". So given that X-24 is a clone of Logan and Logan has a fully functioning brain, there's no reason to believe that X-24 isn't physically able to "think". However, given that X-24 is basically a 'child' who hasn't been taught anything other than "kill kill kill, murda murda murda", it's safe to say that he is just a very very dumb brute!

Comment: What *I* don’t understand is how X-24 represents an improvement over (the) Deadpool.

Comment: He can be controlled, Deadpool can't.

Comment: Unless you're talking about Origins: Wolverine Deadpool, in which case that definitely never happened (ever) so your point is moot anyway.